# Function to convert an arbitrary string for use inside JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, asp-classic, vbscript

I need to write a VBScript function that can convert arbitrary strings into a string that I can safely use inside JavaScript. Something like this:

```
"Hello World"
-- becomes --
"Hello World"

"Hello
World"
-- becomes --
"Hello\nWorld"

"Hello
    World"
-- becomes --
"Hello\n\tWorld"

"Hello'World"
-- becomes --
"Hello\'World"
```

I need to use the function like this:

```
var foo = '<p><%= thatfunction( Recordset( "TextField" ) ) %></p>';
```

I hope you got the point. The function does not have to be bullet-proof but close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Salman A: Here's a Classic ASP function you could use

```
Function thatfunction(ByRef input_string)
    If NOT IsNull(input_string) AND input_string <> "" Then
        Dim working_string
        working_string = input_string
        working_string = Replace(working_string, vbNewLine, "\n")
        working_string = Replace(working_string, vbTab, "\t")
        working_string = Replace(working_string, "'", "\'")
        ' .. other escape values/strings you may wish to add

        thatfunction = working_string
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: It is the "other" values that I'm worried about :)

Comment: @Salman A: Have a look at http://www.the-art-of-web.com/javascript/escape/#section_2 -- you could probably make something similar for Classic ASP using `Server.HTMLEncode` and `Server.URLEncode` to compare the outputs. This should take care of the "other" values. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx)

```
Dim serializer as New JavaScriptSerializer()
Dim jsString as String = serializer.Serialize(your_string_here);
```

---

... but your example shows the text being embedded in an HTML element--not in a Javascript string.  Maybe you're looking for [HttpUtility.HtmlEncode()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73z22y6h.aspx).  Your example might then look like this:

```
<p><%= HttpUtility.HtmlEncode( Recordset( "TextField" ) ) %></p>
```

Comment: I've modified the question a bit. I need classic asp/vbscript solution.